# Copying duplicate values into a new column

Tags: r, pandas

[image]

I am having an issue replicating something in pandas to R.

I want to get the duplicated products with the same Order ID together in a new column

This is how it was done in pandas.

[image: Pandas Code]

I did this [image: My first R code]

and this
[image: Second R code]

I got an error on both.
Any help will be applicated.

I took out the spread function and I got this:

[image]

No value was in the Group_Product column but just <S3: grouped_df>.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You are `spread` into 'wide' format and then assigning to a new column.  Thus, the data would have less number of rows.  In addition, the `paste` at the end wouldnt do anyything

Comment: So, what do you suggest I do to fit it? The original dataset was in a wide format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is done in Pandas: grouping by the `Order_ID` column, then concatenating all `Product` names in those groups. The R+dplyr way follows this structure:

```
library('dplyr')

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
          group_by(carb) %>%
          mutate(alldisp = paste0(disp, collapse = "; ")) %>%
          ungroup()
```

For your dataset:

```
library('dplyr')

temp_sales <- all_sales %>%
              group_by(Order_ID) %>%
              mutate(`Group Product` = paste0(Product, collapse = ", ")) %>%
              ungroup()
```

Comment: This code just copied everything in the product column to the Group_Product column. That is not what I need. Take a look at the result in the pandas' picture. The Group_Product in that dataset has every product values that have the same Oder_ID.

Comment: @HarryPhantom I understood that that's what you wanted. It does work that way on the `mtcars` example dataset, my first example. I don't have your dataset so I cannot adapt it for you. If you can provide a sample of your dataset, I could help you further with that, otherwise you'll have to adapt the example by yourself. My best guess is that your `Order_ID`s are unique; perhaps in some invisible way (spaces?).

Comment: Oh, never mind. It worked. Thanks!!